# Conditional ternary with method call to db

Tags: java, c#, performance, conditional-operator, method-call

So i've been lurking around here for the past few years and have finally come to the situation where I did NOT find an existing answer here. The question itself is pretty simple though.

---

Assume the following statement (no language specific syntax):

```
var result = fetchFromDb() == null ? defaultValue : fetchFromDb().property;
```

What I want to know is: does the compiler in Java or C# have a way to optimise this statement or will there really be two calls to the `fetchFromDb()` method meaning two DB access calls, two execution plans and so on?

I already have tested this in Java and found out that the method is called twice, but I have no idea about eventual caching in the background or anything alike.

So: is using the ternary conditional with methods a bad practice? Is there a way to cache the value compared against inline in order to preserve the beauty of this style?

Comment: var result = fetchFromDbSupplyingDefaultValue(defaultValue);

Comment: It won't get optimized unless it's a well-known function.

Comment: People often think the ternary operator is a replacement for `if`, which it is not. While the style may be attractive in many cases, it just doesn't make sense to attempt to force all ifs to ternary operators (this from a Java/C# perspective).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will always be two calls. The fact is between the first call and the second call, the result of `fetchFromDb()` can change. There is no way for the compiler to predict that change in value, unless it is a well known deterministic `function`. Deterministic being the key word here. Even then there may not be compiler optimization for such things.

Using a ternary condition with methods is not bad practice per se, but it is less readable than a simple if statement.

The only way to guarantee a single call is to code a single call.

```
var result;
var fetchResult = fetchFromDb();
if (fetchResult == null) {
    result = defaultValue;
} else {
    result = result.property;
}
```

Or if you insist on using a ternary

```
var fetchResult = fetchFromDb()
var result = (fetchResult == null) ? defaultValue : result.property;
```

I really think this is much clearer than a ternary. Having code on a single line does not infer beautiful code.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up. Still, it would be nice to have some `value` variable available in the ternary condition, just like you have with a custom property setter in C#... sure, the db could change between the two calls, but why would I care about that change? Would make the comparison senseless at all.

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
var result = fetchFromDb() == null ? defaultValue : fetchFromDb().property;
```

Will make two calls in the `else` case. To avoid the double call:

```
var fetch = fetchFromDb();
var result = fetch != null ? fetch.property : defaultValue;
```